# Online GDB for Fortran: Error: Symbol ‘average1’ at (1) already has basic type of REAL

Tags: text, fortran, gfortran

I am new to programming, as in I am a total beginner.

I am learning Fortran 90, specifically functions. I am not sure why my code returns this when I run it through the online GDB compiler. This is what I receive when I press run:

```
   28 | REAL :: Average1
      |                1
Error: Symbol ‘average1’ at (1) already has basic type of REAL
```

The code I have is:

```
PROGRAM Variation1
! This program will prompt the user for 3 numbers
! then program will then calculate the average of the 3 numbers
! then the program will repeat the same until the user enters "n"
! This is an external function

REAL :: N1, N2, N3
CHARACTER :: answer
REAL :: Average

DO

PRINT *, "Enter 3 numbers:"
READ *, N1, N2, N3
PRINT *, Average(N1, N2, N3)
PRINT *, Average1()

PRINT *, "Would you like to try again?"
READ *, answer
IF (answer=='n') STOP "***Thank you for using our average calculator***"

END DO
!Declare an external function

CONTAINS
REAL FUNCTION Average1()
! REAL :: m1, m2, m3
REAL :: Average1

Average1 = (N1 + N2 + N3)/3

PRINT *, "I'm an external function"
return
END FUNCTION Average1
END PROGRAM Variation1
```

I am getting frustrated with the variables. I try to make this a proper function within a do loop. However, when there is different guides online for different Fortran standards, and the syntax or the way they type the examples for different parts of the code is frustrating. It doesn't compile the same output as the people writing the guides.

I want to get better at understanding and writing Fortran90 or even newer addition Fortran programs in the near future.

Comment: The function declaration statement `REAL FUNCTION Average1()` declares `Average1` to be of type `REAL`.  The subsequent redeclaration, `REAL :: Average1` shouldn't ought to be made too.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You could add the fortran90 tag for version-specific questions, but this one is not. Even if you lear Fortran 90 first, the syntax is mostly universal. I would even recommend learning from a modern resource that does not go strictly in historical steps.